# awk print all but last column + last column

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have kafka topics list with them partition numbers(last digit, delimiter `-`).
Some topics have digit in names like `topic-with-num-in-name-1`.

```
cat /tmp/kafka.txt
topic-with-num-in-name-1-4
topic-without-num-in-name-3
```

Q:
How i can print message like

"Topic: **topic-with-num-in-name-1**" and his partition number: **4**"

or

"Topic: **topic-without-num-in-name**" and his partition number: **3**"
?

I tried like this:

```
cat /tmp/kafka.txt | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="-"}{NF--;}{print}'
```

but can only print topic name:

```
topic-with-num-in-name-1
topic-without-num-in-name
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple `sed` with a greedy regex matching:

```bash
sed -E 's/(.+)-(.+)/Topic: \1 and his partition number: \2/' kafka.txt

Topic: topic-with-num-in-name-1 and his partition number: 4
Topic: topic-without-num-in-name and his partition number: 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Using FS-based extraction:

```
awk -F- '{ printf "\"Topic: %s\" and his partition number: %s\n", $0, $NF }' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following `awk` command:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="-" }{ n=$(NF); NF--; print $0" "n}' kafka.txt
```

---

```
topic-with-num-in-name-1 4
topic-without-num-in-name 3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '{print gensub(/-([^-]*$)/," \\1",1)}' inputfile 
topic-with-num-in-name-1 4
topic-without-num-in-name 3

$ sed -r 's/(.*)-/\1 /' inputfile 
topic-with-num-in-name-1 4
topic-without-num-in-name 3

$ cat inputfile | rev | sed 's/-/ /' | rev
topic-with-num-in-name-1 4
topic-without-num-in-name 3
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following GNU `awk` code.

```
awk '
match($0,/(^.*)-(.*)$/,arr){
   print "Topic: " arr[1] " and his partition number: " arr[2]
}
' Input_file
```